# Mysql Table wont return after indexing

Tags: mysql, myisam

This is a weird one, I have a Mysql table that Crashed... it has 785M rows, and when I repaired it lost the index, when I reapplied the index the table wont return any more results, if I drop the Index it returns with no problem ( just takes a while of course ).

- Tried copying the whole table to another
- Tried to copy only the data
- Tried the to copy to another database

Table table only have 3 columns and its about 14gigs in size using MyISAM.

Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried Optimize?  After the index has been added?

Comment: @Bleach yes, Tried Optimize, Analyse, Check and just to clear my mind... Flush...

Comment: Man. That is a tough one. What happens if you select only the first 1000 rows or so into a new table?  Can you then index and get results. Also, when you say you dont get results, does that mean query never finishes or returns 0 rows?

Comment: @Bleach ... it returns "Empty set (0.01 sec)" all values are BIGINT... it worked normal for over a year... Yeah I tried only the first rows to another table and indexed, it worked just fine... the only thing that comes to mind is to test how much rows the new table can hold before is stops working again... but then again its not a real fix...

Comment: Sorry, no other ideas..Hopefully you now implement replication to restore these in the future. Tables that large are going to constantly give you problems.

Comment: Publish CREATE TABLE query and SELECT query too.

Comment: Consider moving to InnoDB?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.